# MySQL query return all users even with AND selection present

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm returning profiles with images. Since users have more than 1 image I'm trying to limit the results to only one image and avoid seeing "John Smith" 8 times because he has 8 images. I've included "AND" within the following query to achieve this.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON users.user_id = photos.user_id AND photos.selected = 1
```

Issue is I'm not getting all results from the table users, which is the goal. It's spotty and sometimes even removes users who do have an image selected.

I'm not exactly sure if this job lives with the query or with PHP. So I've also pasted it below in case it's relevant and improvements could be made there to help.

So is there anyway to make sure I get ALL results from table.users but still only select 1 image for each user, even if they don't have an image and avoid duplicate results?

```
SELECT 
    users.*, profile_status.*, photos.*, general.*, occupation.*, 
    users.user_id AS userID, user_profile_status.user_id AS profileID
FROM users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_status ON users.user_id = profile_status.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON users.user_id = photos.user_id AND photos.selected = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN general ON users.user_id = general.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN occupation ON users.user_id = occupation.user_id
WHERE 
    users.approved = 1 AND users.admin_level = 0
```

Output:

```
if (!empty($details['filename'])) {
    echo '<a href="/admin/profile?userid=' .$details['userID']. '"><img src="/' . $details['filename'] .'" /></a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="/admin/profile?userid=' .$details['userID']. '"><img src="/assets/images/no-photo.png" /></a>';
}
```

Table

```
Table.photos
photo_id  user_id  filename      selected
1         1        photo_1.jpg   1
2         2        photo_2.jpg   0
3         2        photo_2.jpg   1
4         3        photo_3.jpg   0
5         4        photo_4.jpg   0
```

Comment: How was it? Did GROUP BY work for you? Please accept answer if it did.

Comment: Yeah! Worked like a charm! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be great if you have a condition that will allow you to take only one image (maybe the first image).

But if not, try using GROUP BY to remove the duplicate.
You are selecting a lot of columns so I'll just give you an example:

```
GROUP BY users.user_id
```

This will cause MySQL to return one row per user_id.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to combine both ORDER BY and GROUP BY? I may need to ORDER BY as well something like: `ORDER BY ss_users.last_login GROUP BY users.user_id`

Comment: Also, I guess I will have to remove `AND photos.selected = 1` and then GROUP BY. I won't be able to make sure it's the photo they selected?

Comment: If you use GROUP BY then your selection list must not contain items other than the grouping column(s) and aggregate functions of the groups.  That doesn't look like it's going to work for the original query presented.

Comment: @Jamie, yes you can use ORDER BY together with GROUP BY. Try it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you don't have to select any column that you have on your GROUP BY. Try it first on your MySQL. You'll be enlightened.

Comment: @gmarintes No, you don't have to select the grouping columns.  The point is that you *cannot* select non-grouping columns.  To be more precise than my previous comment, you can select grouping columns, aggregate functions of the groups, constants, and / or expressions built from those.  Nothing else.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you CAN select non-grouping columns. MySQL will return the first matching data for that column. Try creating a dummy table and just try it. What you're saying is something that I believed was true many years ago until I tried it myself.

Comment: @gmarintes such queries as you describe are not valid SQL, but a quick bit of research shows that MySQL indeed does allows them as an extension.  It explicitly does not, however, define *which* row provides values for selection items that are not grouping columns.  In any case, I cannot recommend relying on such an extension.  At best, doing so fosters bad habits.  At worst, it comes back to bite you when you can least afford it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yes, MySQL has GROUP BY extensions documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html, it says "this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group", which may be the case for the OPs database. See how he's joining the other tables with users table.

Comment: @gmarintes I do see that.  And I see that for each table he is selecting *all* columns.  Therefore, either there will be in each group at least one column for which the nonaggregated values are not all equal, or else a better solution would be to remove duplicate rows from the source tables.

Comment: @gmarintes After testing with `GROUP BY users.user_id` I notice some results go missing. Any user who had multiple images represented have now been omitted completely from results

Comment: Actually, `ss_user_profile_status.user_id` might have done the trick, although I need to double check. Now i'm thoroughly confused. I need to get reading up on this

Answer (score 0):

Making the users table leftmost in a series of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s ensures that each of its rows is represented *at least* once.  A `users` row *R* may be represented more than once in the overall join result if any of the tables joined to `users` has more than one row matching the join condition for row *R*.

The best solution is probably to add appropriate join criteria or `WHERE` predicates to filter out unwanted rows.  This is what you have done with respect to the `photos` table already, but if you're still getting duplicate rows then you need to do similarly for the `general` and/or `occupation` table.  This is a matter of determining what your data mean, and exactly which you are trying to select.  For example, if you want only one row per user, but users may have multiple occupations, then which occupation do you want?  And if you don't care, then why are you joining and selecting the occupation data at all?

Following from that, the other main alternative is to omit the `general` and/or `occupation` table from the query -- whichever one is producing multiple rows.  Perhaps you actually want two or even three separate queries instead of doing everything with one.

Comment: Thanks John. Make sense. The only thing I should have noted is that  `photos` is the only table which contains multiple data per user. The other tables only have 1 matching row.

Comment: If you are getting multiple rows per users.user_id, then one of the following must be true: (1) there are multiple rows in `users` with the same `user_id`; or (2) there are multiple rows in one or more of the joined tables with the same `user_id`, and the join and selection predicates are insufficiently selective.  Either one is a problem that you should understand and solve.  Hacking around it with GROUP BY is not a solution -- it just pushes the problem under the rug for you to deal with later.